# LAN Application with shared files

Tags: c#, deployment, lan

I've written a c# application which is intended to be ran on multiple computers within a network. The problem im trying to figure out is how I can share some common files between all the computers within the network.

I was handling this before by installing the software on one computer, storing a path string as an application scope setting during install, and then creating exe shortcuts on all other computers in the network which point back to the original installs exe.

[Application deployment to network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930927/application-deployment-to-network-drive)

I read this link and they talked about how it would be better to use clickonce rather than using a network share. The network share was the only way I could think of to have a common files directory. Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the installation process should ask the user for the path where the shared files will go.  As long as each user enters the same path your good.  That's the trick...

One way to solve that is to provide a silent installer mode that can be run with a preset of values the installer will need.  You can then push the installer via group policy to all of the machines in your network.

I'm not sure what installer tech you are using, but [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) will create MSI's that support silent installation.